# No option during facebook store setup to checkout in another website

Tags: facebook

I am trying to create a Facebook store for my Facebook page with the checkout leading to my website and not Facebook. When setting up the store I am not given an option to do it. I have seen it in some tutorials showing this [choosing checkout option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT3ZV.png). Is there a way to get to the checkout option?

Comment: If you're finding this question since Facebook rolled out Shops https://twitter.com/Facebook/status/1262792529042239489 unfortunately I still cannot find any way to change the checkout option. The API is also not yet available to the public so if you're hoping to connect to your own system you can't yet do that.

Answer (score 2):

Found [this video](https://youtu.be/A59J1Mdqccs) by Mexbs that explains how to overcome the issue. In short, here are the steps:

1. Change the location of your Facebook page to Germany (or some other country that Facebook didn't limit yet)
2. Add the Shop tab and proceed with the Shop setup. "Checkout on another website" and "Message to buy" should be available now.
3. Add one product to your shop (so Facebook won't delete your shop tab once you change the page location back to the original).
4. Change the page location back to your original location.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this feature was available before FB had its own payment method.  Even though you can manage your catalog and add a product url, the checkout button only goes through the FB interface.   I am going to ask FB tech support if there is currently a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found this yet either and would be stoked if someone can give a clear answer. I've found that if you add products from the Catalog section, you can add a website link for each product which is described by FB as, "a link to the website page where people can view more details and buy this product."

However, my store page is all sorts of mangled at the moment and I'm (sloowwwwlllyyyy) working with FB to get it all sorted out so I can't tell if it's actually working as I'm hoping it does.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I know you can't add comments at the moment, but for future reference be aware that this would probably be best added as a comment, given that you don't have a formal answer as yet. When I was in a similar situation as a new user, I was advised to stick, until I could comment, to answering questions for which I could add a clear answer without needing clarification (or something along those lines). That might be a good approach for you also.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who stumbles on this thread and needs help finding the answer to this problem...

When you click the shop tab to start the setup process DO NOT choose the United States as your location. Choose your location as literally any other location, I did Canada. When you do, it wont try to force you to use Facebook's automatic checkout. It will immediately pop up with the option to buy through messages or direct them to your website. This does not change the location of your actual page either, just choose another country when it asks you right at the shop set up process.

Because of the kind of product I sell I *cant* accept returns. I needed the ability to send them to my store